# How to pass list to query data with Firestore?

Tags: python, google-cloud-firestore

When I query data using Firestore, this works:

```
doc_ref = db.document(u'myPath')
doc = doc_ref.get()
print doc.to_dict()['a']['b']['c']
```

If I have `x = ['a', 'b', 'c']`, how do I pass it with `doc.to_dict()`command to get the same result as above? Or how should I modify `x`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally made it work by using the following approach.

```
doc_ref = db.document(u'myPath')
doc = doc_ref.get()
x = ['a', 'b', 'c']
print reduce(lambda val, key: val.get(key) if val else None, x, doc.to_dict())
```